# How would you translate "circumferens" in this passage from St. Augustine's Confessions?

Tags: vocabulary, augustinus

I'm reading the beginning of St. Augustine's *Confessions* (Liber I Caput I), and had some trouble translating the word *circumferens*. How would you translate it?

> magnus es, domine, et laudabilis valde. magna virtus tua et sapientiae
>   tuae non est numerus. et laudare te vult homo, aliqua portio creaturae
>   tuae, et homo circumferens mortalitatem suam, circumferens testimonium
>   peccati sui et testimonium quia superbis resistis; et tamen laudare te
>   vult homo, aliqua portio creaturae tuae.
>
> Great you are, Lord, and very praiseworthy: great is your virtue, and
>   of your wisdom there is no number. And this man wishes to praise you, to
>   some extent a part of your creation, and this man carrying about him a
>   testimony of his own sin and a testimony that you resist the proud;
>   and yet this man wishes to praise you, to some extent a part of your
>   creation.

I'm afraid my translation might not read very well, so any other tips would be appreciated. Also, why is the demonstrative *this* implied with homo? I couldn't figure that one out.

Comment: Why do you think "this" is implied? Just after the portion you quoted, Augustine has his famous "fecisti **nos** ad te," so I don't think he's just talking about himself.

Comment: @brianpck Oh, thanks for the comment. I was referring to another English translation to see how the translator translated "homo", and they used the word *this*. That's why.

Comment: Your translation is extremely literal. There's nothing wrong with this if you are using it as a crib for the Latin, but if you want it to stand alone in English, I could suggest some more idiomatic expressions.

Comment: I can also add that you seem to have overlooked translating *mortalitatem suam*.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of sounding like I'm suggesting some schoolboy calque, I think translating *circumferens* as "carrying around" is pretty spot on. Man is carrying around his mortality and his various testimonies.

I don't think you need the "this". I think that these gratuitous *this*es were a common idiom in 19th century English. I don't hear them much in more recent literature.